# pay for flight reservation only after approval of visa application?

Tags: visas

For many visa applications, you need a flight reservation that shows you have purchased a round trip to your destination and back. But when you buy a flight there is a change your visa application won't be approved and then you already spent money. Yes, I know you can get cancellation insurance, but you have to do some extra administrative work before you get your money back.

So is it possible to make a flight reservation without paying for it right away and pay for it after you visa application is approved?

Comment: Buy a fully refundable ticket, after visa cancel and rebook a cheaper ticket for actual travel dates?

Comment: Can you give examples of a visa application that requires a paid ticket in advance?

Comment: @pnuts, interested to know where the OP's question is based: i.e., who requires a paid ticket as evidence?  I can understand reservations, or concrete plans, just interested in where paid tickets are required.

Comment: @pnuts I hardly think the spelling mistakes, lack of capitalization, and mispunctuation are helping everyone interpret the OPs requirements.

Comment: @pnuts really? The intent seems the same - "how do I resolve the issue of putting down money on a flight ticket, when there's the chance the visa will be refused?"

Comment: @pnuts, OK, yeah, maybe :) I'd rather the OP themselves clarified. Not going to push the point, I still consider it a dupe, but it takes more than just me...

Comment: Voting to close.  Without knowing who requires a paid ticket in advance, it's too broad.  Not the UK, not Schengen.

Comment: @pnuts with a Credit card, if you time it right, you can get away with 0 payments up front...

Comment: @pnuts, the question says "...for many visa applications..." Is it so hard to give a concrete example?

Answer (score 3):

You can buy trip cancellation insurance.

Visa refusal is covered by all policies that I've ever seen (and used.)

Comment: Ummm... determining OP intent and rewriting questions based on your assumption is not what editing is for.

Comment: Assuming the OP returns to the site.

Comment: @pnuts, remember that these questions are not only for the OP, but for future visitors to the site as well, so the questions should be left as general as possible unless the OP makes it more specific.

Answer (score 2):

What I've seen  people do is to get a fully refundable ticket which costs way higher than a normal low fare ticket. The advantage is that you can cancel this ticket and get all the money you put upfront if you happen to change your plans.